# Почему одна часть письма нормальна, а другая не в нужной кодировке?

Tags: php, email

Делаю отправку писем через функцию mail (пробовал через PHPmailer тоже самое), часть текста письма не подставляемого в нормальной кодировке, а другая часть в какой-то неведомой кодировке.

Код:

```
$to = 'info@site.ru';
                                                $hd="Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
                                                $hd.="From: SITE.RU <info@site.ru>\r\n";
                                                $hd.="X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion()."\r\n";
                                                $subject = 'Вам назначили задачу "'.$myrow_tasks['title'].'"!';
                                                $mess='
                                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" style="margin:0;padding:0;width:700px;line-height:100%;border-collapse:collapse">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td valign="top" style="border-collapse:collapse"> 
                                                            <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" style="background-color:#49769c;width:100%;color:white;font-family:sans-serif;margin-top:10px;padding:8px;border-collapse:collapse">
                                                                <tbody>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td width="115" height="50" valign="middle" style="border-collapse:collapse;margin:10px;">
                                                                            <img src="http://site.ru/images/logo-150x47.png" alt="PLP" width="107" style="outline:none;margin:10px;text-decoration:none;display:block">
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td width="200" valign="middle" style="padding-left:20px;border-collapse:collapse">- система обработки клиентов с вашего сайта</td>
                                                                        <td width="400" valign="middle" style="text-align:right;border-collapse:collapse">
                                                                            <div style="margin-right:20px">
                                                                                <a href=http://account.site.ru/login/ style="color:white" target="_blank">Вход в личный кабинет</a>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </tbody>
                                                            </table>
                                                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" style="border-collapse:collapse">
                                                                <tbody><tr>
                                                                    <td width="600" height="300px"; valign="middle" style="border-collapse:collapse">
                                                                        <div style="margin:20px 10px">
                                                                                Здравствуйте!
                                                                                <br><br>
                                                                                <h2>Вам поставили задачу "'.$myrow_tasks['title'].'".</h2>
                                                                                <br><br>
                                                                                Статус: '.$status_tasck.'
                                                                                <br><br>
                                                                                Дата начала: '.new_time(strtotime(''.$myrow_tasks['start_date'].' '.$myrow_tasks['start_time'].'')).'
                                                                                <br><br>
                                                                                Дата дедлайна: '.new_time(strtotime(''.$myrow_tasks['end_date'].' '.$myrow_tasks['end_time'].'')).'
                                                                                <br><br>
                                                                                Дата дедлайна: '.$myrow_tasks['description'].';
                                                                                <br><br>
                                                                                <i style="color:#666">С уважением, команда сервиса SITE!</i>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </tbody>
                                                            </table>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td valign="top" style="border-collapse:collapse"> 
                                                                <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="background-color:#49769c;width:100%;color:white;font-family:sans-serif;margin-top:10px;border-collapse:collapse">
                                                                    <tbody>
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td valign="middle" align="left" style="width:130px;border-collapse:collaps;padding-left:20px;">
                                                                            Присоединяйтесь:    
                                                                            </td>
                                                                            <td valign="middle" align="left" style="width:35px;border-collapse:collapse;padding-left:5px;">
                                                                                <a href="https://vk.com/" target="_blank" style=" padding-right:5px;"><img src="http://site.ru/images/vk_30px.jpg" alt="Вконтакте" width="30px" border="0" style="margin:5px;outline:none;text-decoration:none;" /></a> 
                                                                            </td>
                                                                            <td valign="middle" align="left" style="width:35px;border-collapse:collapse;padding-left:5px;">
                                                                                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><img src="http://site.ru/images/fb_30px.jpg" alt="FaceBook" width="30px" border="0" style="margin:5px;outline:none;text-decoration:none;" /></a> 
                                                                            </td>
                                                                            <td valign="middle" align="left" style="width:35px;border-collapse:collapse;padding-left:5px;">
                                                                                <a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank"><img src="http://site.ru/images/tw_30px.jpg" alt="Twitter" width="30px" border="0" style="margin:5px;outline:none;text-decoration:none;" /></a>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                            <td valign="middle" align="left" style="width:500px;border-collapse:collapse;padding-left:5px;">

                                                                            </td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                    </tbody>
                                                                </table>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>';
                                                mail ($to,$subject,$mess,$hd);
```

**Как поправить?** Приложил приходящее письмо... [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Потому что верхняя часть в кодировке UTF-8 (неверная кодировка), а "привет" в нормальной почтовой кодировке KOI8-R (вероятнее всего так). Функции работы с почтой часто, к сожелению, требуют KOI8 кодировку.

Comment: @nick_n_a, как это поправить чтобы нормально работало?

Comment: еще веселее стало =) https://i.gyazo.com/438a8a4896436640b5e355bace05e98a.png

Comment: Верхняя часть точно UTF-8. Нижняя... наверное таки Windows-1251. В php есть функции смены кодировки. Нужно привести всё в одну кодировку (поменять кодировку той части текста которая неверно отображается).

Comment: @nick_n_a, не ну это же пролный пи**ц https://i.gyazo.com/65b23d5134c77fe9dd918c1f39bcff92.png